# How to get user_id using access token from twitter?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to get `user_id` based on `access_token` from Twitter.

Similar to facebook: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={accessToken}`

How can I get similar results using Twitter API, Where I will hit Twitter API using `access_token`?

Android app developer sending me userID and authToken when they login using twitter login button on their end (android app). 
So now I want get user profile detail using this authToken.
Please explain me the authToken use and how can get profile detail. Also provide example or reference so , I can understand and implement.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Did you try looking at the [API reference](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference)?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Could you confirm that you have both the access token key and and access token secret from twitter? These two are sufficient to retrieve the users id.

Comment: @Mehdi:  I have   auth_token of other user who clicked to login with twitter buttion. Mobile app dev  send me auth_token after login. Now at server I want get profile data of other user using his auth_token

Comment: @SandeepKumarThakur Please update your question by adding the precisions from last comment, so that people reading your question understand that this is about 'Sing in with twitter' buton, and 'auth token'.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrieve the user Id if you have an access token (both the access token key and the access token secret).

The API endpoint to do this is `account/verify_credentials`, cf. [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials).

This means that technically, you are able to use twitter API on behalf of the users by storing only their access tokens, no need to keep their userId or usernames in your database - although it would be more convenient to keep these available at hand.

Also important: in the result object, you probably want to use `id_str` rather than `id`, [as recommended](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake), as numerical `id` may not be parsed correctly.

Proof-of-concept code in node.js, the same can be achieved in php.

setup:

```
$ cd /tmp/
$ npm install tuiter
$ node
```

Then in node:

```
var keys = {
    "consumer_key" : "xxx"
  , "consumer_secret" : "yyy" 
  , "access_token_key" : "zzzzzzzzzz-zzzz"
  , "access_token_secret" : "aaaaaaa"
}

var tu = require('tuiter')(keys)

tu.verifyCredentials(function(err, res) {
    if (err)
        throw err

    console.log('user id is', res.id_str) // prints the user id
})
```

**Edit**

OP precised that the tokens he is referring to are `auth_token` from the "SIgn in with twitter" button.

As per the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing):

> A successful response contains the `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret` parameters. The token and token secret should be stored and used for future authenticated requests to the Twitter API. To determine the identity of the user, use [GET account / verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials).

The answer provided above should still work then.

Comment: Down voting because `account/verify_credentials` requires authentication with full credentials. The question assumes only the user's access token is available -- i.e. given any access token, how does one get the associated `user_id`.

Comment: @Jonas thanks for the comment. My answer was perhaps unclear. I confirm that the access tokens are sufficient authentify the user, and to retrieve the user Id. Cf. updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for down voting, but your answer explains how to get the user_id from an authenticated user. I read the question differently. I think the question is asking the following. If I give you only my twitter access token can you retrieve my twitter user_id?

Comment: No worries. The answer is yes. The access token is what "authentifies" the user, no need of further action from him ;)

Comment: If the answer is yes, can you add an example of this to your answer? In other words, assume `tu` (above) is already authenticated with *your* credentials. Now, I give you my access token. What API call would retrieve my user_id? In your example, `account/verify_credentials` retrieves your user_id.

Comment: @Jonas In the fourth and fifth lines of the example, just put access token of any of your app user, to retrieve their Ids. The rest of the code does not need to be changed.

Comment: access secret (not access token) goes in line 5. Again, I think we are reading the question differently. I read it as "get user_id based on access_token" and nothing else (i.e. no no access secret).

Comment: On twitter, access token is composed by a key and a secret key. Both of these are obtained together. Why would OP have one and not the other? https://dev.twitter.com/oauth#user-authentication

Comment: Ahh, now I see the confusion. When I was referring to an access token I was using Twitter's definition which is not *both* key and secret. What you are calling `access_token_key` in your code, Twitter call this the access token. If you go to Twitter's Application Management webpage -- the page where you get your application credentials from -- you will see what I mean. I had a feeling we were answering different questions.

Comment: I have auth_token of other user who clicked to login with twitter buttion. Mobile app dev send me auth_token after login. Now at server I want get profile data of other user using his auth_token.

Comment: @SandeepKumarThakur I have updated the answer accordingly. Have you tried anything? Did you read the documentation? Solution should work, you just need to try!

Comment: Do you have any example for getting profile details of twitter account including emailID . I have used the package "react-native-login-twitter" for my react-native application. Authentication is successfull and I got authToken, authTokenSecret of the profile but email is empty. Is there any second call required to get more profile infos using authToken & authTokenSecret . If so please help .. Thank you :)